# Remove specific character from the string in Python

Tags: python

I have a string data, let say`['josh,john,jake']`
I want to remove `['` and `']` so i can use `split(",")` function to get my data. How to do it?

Comment: That a string or a list...

Comment: `['josh,john,jake']` is not string data. It's a list of one element.

Comment: can someone told me how to get my data even though its a list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use strip():

```
s = "['josh,john,jake']"
s.strip("[']").split(",")
```

*Edit: Replaced variable name "str" by "s"*

Comment: `str=...` is a sure way to a disaster. Hint: `str` is a string constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can use string slicing.

```
In [2]: s = "['josh,john,jake']"

In [3]: s1 = s[2:-2]

In [4]: s1
Out[4]: 'josh,john,jake'

In [5]: s1.split(',')
Out[5]: ['josh', 'john', 'jake']
```